# Where vs. Having with calculated field

Tags: sql

I'm looking for total of all the people in a population between a certain age.  The query I tried below gives a count of every age.  E.g. I'm looking for 5-10 years, and the query gives me a count of each individual age instead of returning a single number

```
select datediff(yyyy,dob,admitdate) as age, count(datediff(yyyy,dob,admitdate) as counts
from myTable
group by datediff(yyyy,dob,admitdate)
having (count(datediff(yyyy,dob,admitdate) between 5 and 10)
```

This isn't correct, but the things that I tried (like removing HAVING and using WHERE) haven't worked.

Comment: try making the select as follows: count(*) as age

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select count(*) as counts
from myTable
where datediff(yyyy,dob,admitdate) between 5 and 10
```

Answer (score 1):

1. remove the `group by` clause
2. change `having` to `where` and remove `count`
3. don't select `age`, **do** select `count(*)`

Comment: can you give me a quick explanation as to why count(*) works here?

Comment: @woots when you use an aggregating function, such as `count`, with no `group by` clause, it puts the entire result set in a single group.  Then, `count(*)` means "just count the number of rows in the group".

Comment: Ah, ok.  Taking a step back and thinking about it you count all possible records, but since you don't select them they don't show up in your query.